# Drupal Module padding depending on background-color

Tags: css, html, drupal, module, frontend

I am only in the theorizing stages of this and would love some input.  I am developing a site for a client in Drupal that will contain over 250 pages.  I have broken the site down into 22 modules.  I am about half-way through the project and am starting to realize an issue that will come up.  The client will be able to go into the back end and determine the background color of each module (grey or white).  I am seeing that I will run into an issue with the padding of each module.  Every module should be separated by 40 pixels, so each module has a top and bottom padding of 20 pixels.  This is based on the design of having one background color for each module.  However if the modules contain different background colors, then there would need to be a total of 80 pixels separating them (per the approved design). This becomes even more complicated for table and mobile as things break out of their containers, but I'll go down that road when I solve the initial issue.  Like I said, I'm just now starting to think about a solution and am hoping for some input to get my brain motion.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assign a class to the grey background templates and a different class to the white background templates, then assign background color (grey or white) as well as padding separate for either. 

Your client will be assigning a class rather than a background color. This is a pure CSS issue, as I understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the response and input.  Unfortunately, this won't solve the problem.  The issue is not determining what padding to use depending on what background color is selected.  The issue lies with being able to determine padding dependent of the sequence of background colors.  For instance if two modules with the same background color are in sequence, then padding will be different if a grey background module follows a white one.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What does any of this have to do with Drupal Modules? Modules for Drupal are collections of code that add on functionality. From the sounds of it whatever you're trying to do is not Drupal specific and when you refer to module do you actually mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry you are correct.  I am developing the front-end for custom Drupal modules for a backend dev to implement in Drupal.  I realize I shouldn't have referred to them as Drupal modules.  My problem is specific to css.  I apologize for any confusion.  What I was referring to are simply containers/blocks of html.  What I need is a way to say, for example... if a grey background container follows a white background container...then this padding should exist.  If a white container follows a white container...then this padding should exist on each child.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is fairly straightforward. The backend needs to check the sequence and output a specific class regarding the spacing of each block taking into the consideration the block position..

From a CSS perspective, the spacing class will have to be independent from the color of the block class, since the spacing is related to the sequence of the blocks and not the color of each block itself.

Hope this helps!